# How to pass/return records with PascalMock requiring Variants?

Tags: mocking, record, delphi-2010, pascalmock

PascalMock with Delphi 2010 works fine when using simple data types or objects. With records, however, there's trouble.

`TMock.Returns` takes an array of `TVarRec`, so I can't just pass a one in.

There is a sample which casts it to a pointer, but since it represents a value, that doesn't make sense to me. When that record is going to get passed between some functions, in the end I'll get back a copy with a different address.

Another thing I tried was to copy the record at the byte level into a `Variant` using `VarArrayCreate`. This mysteriously results into an error casting to integer when fed to PascalMock. I get the same error when I just pass in `Variant(TBytes.Create(1, 2, 3))`. Without the explicit case to `Variant`, again I get an integer (pointer?).

Of course I could always write a mock completely by hand, but given the age of PascalMock I expected this to be a solved issue. Note that I'm not even using the latest `AutoMockIntf` addition. Is there a proper way of converting any record to/from a Variant that PascalMocks can work with? Or is there perhaps a better way to work with records in this context?

Here's some sample code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
interface

uses
  SysUtils,
  TestFramework,
  PascalMock;

type
  TMyRecord = record
    // Sample fields but should work for any record structure
    FirstField: Integer;
    SecondField: string;
    class operator Equal(const A, B: TMyRecord): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const A, B: TMyRecord): Boolean;
  end;

  IRecordMaker = interface
  ['{436D6FC3-3DCD-4EFF-B206-1C3E1A5561D1}']
    function Make: TMyRecord;
  end;

  TFakeRecordMaker = class(TMock, IRecordMaker)
  public
    function Make: TMyRecord;
  end;

  IRecordSaver = interface
  ['{91BB1347-A34E-4A77-8993-3ADBFBE8726D}']
    procedure Save(const ARecord: TMyRecord);
  end;

  TFakeRecordSaver = class(TMock, IRecordSaver)
  public
    procedure Save(const ARecord: TMyRecord);
  end;

  TRunner = class
  private
    FRecordMaker: IRecordMaker;
    FRecordSaver: IRecordSaver;
  public
    constructor Create(ARecordMaker: IRecordMaker; ARecordSaver: IRecordSaver);
    procedure Run;
  end;

  TestRunner = class(TTestCase)
  private
    FRecordMaker: TFakeRecordMaker;
    FRecordSaver: TFakeRecordSaver;
  protected
    procedure SetUp; override;
    procedure TearDown; override;
  published
    procedure MakesRecordAndSavesIt;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyRecord }

class operator TMyRecord.Equal(const A, B: TMyRecord): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (A.FirstField = B.FirstField) and (A.SecondField = B.SecondField);
end;

class operator TMyRecord.NotEqual(const A, B: TMyRecord): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (A = B);
end;

{ TFakeRecordMaker }

function TFakeRecordMaker.Make: TMyRecord;
begin
  // Remember having been called and return the desired data
  Result := AddCall('Make').ReturnValue;
end;

{ TFakeRecordSaver }

procedure TFakeRecordSaver.Save(const ARecord: TMyRecord);
begin
  // Remember having been called and with what arguments
  AddCall('Save').WithParams([ARecord]);
end;

{ TRunner }

constructor TRunner.Create(ARecordMaker: IRecordMaker; ARecordSaver: IRecordSaver);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FRecordMaker := ARecordMaker;
  FRecordSaver := ARecordSaver;
end;

procedure TRunner.Run;
var
  LRecord: TMyRecord;
begin
  LRecord := FRecordMaker.Make;
  FRecordSaver.Save(LRecord);
end;

{ TestRunner }

procedure TestRunner.SetUp;
begin
  inherited;
  FRecordMaker := TFakeRecordMaker.Create;
  FRecordSaver := TFakeRecordSaver.Create;
end;

procedure TestRunner.MakesRecordAndSavesIt;
var
  LRecord: TMyRecord;
  LSUT: TRunner;
begin
  // The test data
  LRecord.FirstField := 3;
  LRecord.SecondField := 'bla';
  // The first collaborator serving as stub should return this data
  FRecordMaker.Expects('Make').Returns(LRecord);
  // The second collaborator serving as mock should be passed this data
  FRecordSaver.Expects('Save').WithParams([LRecord]);
  LSUT := TRunner.Create(FRecordMaker, FRecordSaver);
  try
    // Hopefully the SUT will get the data and pass it on
    LSUT.Run;
    // Check if the remembered calls match the expected ones
    FRecordSaver.Verify;
  finally
    LSUT.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TestRunner.TearDown;
begin
  FRecordSaver.Free;
  FRecordMaker.Free;
  inherited;
end;

initialization
  RegisterTest(TestRunner.Suite);

end.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a record you are having trouble with? What are you trying to mock with it exactly?

Comment: And what is it you are trying to solve? To have `Returns()` check every field of the returned record to make sure they match the values in the record you give to `Returns()`? And to have `WithParams()` check the same thing? Looking at PascalMock's source, I don't think it has that capability. I might be reading it wrong, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What I'm looking for is this (or similar) code to give the same effect it would have when instead of records I would be processing integers. Somewhere down the call stack of `TMock.Verify` some `Variant`s are compared to determine of the expectations were met. So I suppose the real question is how to get a record into a `Variant` that can be processed correctly by PascalMock.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I annotated the source some more in case you (or others) are not very familiar with the workings of PascalMock.

Comment: Unlike `Integer` and other built-in types, `Variant` does not natively support records. You would have to [define a custom Variant type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Defining_Custom_Variants_Index) via [`TCustomVariantType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Variants.TCustomVariantType) to represent your record data and provide copy/assignment/comparison operators for it. You could then store your record data in a `Variant` variable and pass it to `Returns()`. I don't know if you would be able to use the same variable with `WithParams()`, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85250/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-thijs-van-dien).